# Python Numerical Integration Without SciPy?

Tags: python, math, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I need to integrate the function: ***y(x) = e<sup>-ax</sup>cos(x)*** without using SciPy/NumPy etc. I am struggling quite a bit. I know this:

```
def integrand(x):
                return
```

For the return bit I want to use this equation:the sum from `i=1` to `N` of ***y(xi)(xi - x(i-1))***

How would I go about writing this?

Comment: The sum is probably from `1` to **`N-1`**?

Answer (score 4):

Simply define it as:

```
from math import cos, e

def y(x):
    return (e**(-a*x))*cos(x)

def integrand(x):
    return sum(y(x[i])*(x[i]-x[i-1]) for i in range(1,len(x)))
```

The `range(1,len(x))` ranges from 1 (inclusive) to the length of `x` (exclusive).

Or use:

```
from math import exp, cos

def y(x):
    return exp(-a*x)*cos(x)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, i'm now lost as to how to proceed. I am so use to being able to use SciPy. I want it to print the values for the integral when 'a' = 0.

Comment: Yes, I have done this. Just unsure on how to proceed from here.

Comment: Well as in your other question you create a `x = linspace(..)` and call `integrand(x)`...

Comment: the name 'linspace' is not defined?

Comment: @webberwizard: `from numpy import linspace`??

Comment: It only prints out the value 0.0

Comment: @webberwizard: the answer should be [0.0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(e%5E-ax)*cos(x)+from+0+to+4*pi+with+a+%3D+0)

Comment: Oh my god, yes of course, my bad. I am sorry- I have realised this now. All is good, thank you!